# The dots and const in printf function

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code in c++:

```
int printf(const char *p,...);
int main()
{
    printf("Stack Overflow\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It returned an error :

```
/home/tWi2Su/ccnhXznj.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x17): undefined reference to `printf(char const*, ...)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But when I remove the `const`, I get the following error :

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:4:27: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
  printf("Stack Overflow\n");
                           ^
/home/a5vnrT/cclz99Yy.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x17): undefined reference to `printf(char*, ...)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I remove the `dots`, I get the following error :

```
/home/3jQpK8/cc01lRrz.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x17): undefined reference to `printf(char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Compilation error   time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0

prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:4:27: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
  printf("Stack Overflow\n");
                           ^
/home/a5vnrT/cclz99Yy.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x17): undefined reference to `printf(char*, ...)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is it necessary to give dots here when I am the one declaring the function (and not predifining it). Moreover when we pass a string to a function in c++, we do not need to mention `const`. Then why is necessary to give the `const` keyword here?

Comment: Hmm..., I always found more info looking under **variadic**, but **dots** might work...

Comment: The ellipses (dots) is not necessary here and has nothing to do with `const`.

Comment: Side-question: why are you trying to declare `printf` yourself instead of `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: #Offtopic: [another popular use of `dots`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOTS_(Directly_Observed_Treatment,_Short-Course)) :-) (no offense)

Comment: Not that you *should* declare `printf()` yourself, but have you tried: `extern "C" int printf(const char *, ...);`?

Answer (score 7):

In your case,

```
int printf(const char *p, ...);
int main()
{
    printf("Stack Overflow\n");
    return 0;
}
```

you only have a *declaration*, no definition of `printf()`. Linker is shouting.

Regarding the (missing) `const` type-qualifier,  in `C++`, a string literal, (narrow string literals) has a type *“array of n `const char`”,* and when you try to pass that to a `char *`, type mismatch happens.

That said, those dots, `...` are used as the notation of a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) which can accept variable number of arguments.

Comment: In C writing your own declaration for a standard library function is allowed. In C++ it isn't.